# Can i connect a python server with a kotlin client?

Tags: python, kotlin, sockets, server

I'm making a cryptocoin app with my friends and i used to make app with python until i got several error on buildozer and python-for-android for days. I can't build apk so i decided to switch to kotlin and curious about something. This app will run with help of a python bot which is running on a server. Can i connect a python server with kotlin client and dump json data sended from python server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. You can consume APIs with Android Retrofit library. In Google official docs you find a codelab on how to use it.